# Magento prevent invoice email

Tags: email, magento, invoice

with magento 1.9.0.1 invoicing emails are always sent with each order. How can I stop the email? The invoice should be created of course, but not sent to the customer automatically

edit:
or is it possible to attach the invoice directly to order information email?

regards
matt

Answer (score 1):

You can disable the invoice email in System > Configuration > Sales Emails then look for invoice and set 'enabled' to 'no'.

This completely disables the invoice email from sending, but the invoice is still created.